# what does fewer lines mean in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are "3 fewer lines" in status bar?
What does it mean?

[image]

I can't find it on the web.

Comment: What extensions do you have enabled? Extensions can add many different things to the status bar.

Comment: Welcome! Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: I'm guessing this is some kind of diff indicator from an extension (gitlens?) (though I could very well be wrong)

Comment: @all  you are right. I think user is correct. i just have tow extensions Vim and gitlens.